# How do I detect Google account deletion?

Tags: google-oauth

I've just started working with Google OAUTH2 in order to add a "Sign in with Google" button to my web site.

According to the ["Google+ Platform Developer Policies"](https://developers.google.com/+/policies) section B.2.a.III, if a user deletes their Google account, I must delete all personal information I obtained from the Google API relating to them.

Does this apply to my web application as well? And if so, how do I detect that a user's Google account no longer exists? Surely, a successful login will only occur if the Google account exists; so how can I tell if a previously existing account is no longer there?

Comment: What a great paradox :-)   If the user deletes their Google account, they will be unable to authenticate to your site, so will be unable to request that you delete their data. I can't wait to see the official answer :-)

Comment: My reading of https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/#revoking_access_tokens_and_disconnecting_the_app says that you have to provide a "disconnect" action and if the user explicitly hits it, you have to wipe that data. Which seems reasonable. I'm not sure how you detect that a Google account has been deleted... will check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe someone has a better approach, but a simple and practical solution would be have a link buried somewhere on your site that allows a user to request account deletion via email (assuming you still possess a valid email for him - if he deletes is Gmail and that's all you have then you have no way to contact him other than manually via phone or something).

The doc you link to says `Give users a reasonably convenient way to delete any of their personal information you’ve obtained from the API.`

So assuming you still have a valid email address, this would work:

- Your FAQ says "What if I want to delete my account?".  Links to account deletion page.
- Account deletion page: What's your email? ***_*____** (Continue)
- Email is sent to user with (securely randomized) confirmation link.
- Confirmation link is clicked by user which deletes all of his data from your site.

Success of that process is dependent only on your system and the email arriving.

(If you are concerned about complying to EU data protection law, you might want to implement this feature anyway - since one legally has the right to demand the deletion of one's own personal data.)

Comment: Well, yes, that might be a good idea. But when you read the relevant section of the Developer Policies, you get the impression that there is some automatic mechanism that I need to implement. But perhaps that's just the lawyers writing without conferring with the developers.

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean.  Looks like your guess about the legal and devs not talking to each other is about as good an explanation as we're going to get, unfortunately.